# What's the best filesystem to share between OS X and Ubuntu?

Tags: filesystem, macosx, fat32

Got a MacBook Air 3,1 11" w/ 128GB SSD. Configuring for dual boot. I intend to have a shared drive where I'll store my media. What filesystem is best?

They say FAT32 is best for cross-platform compatibility, but the maximum size for file transfer is 4GB, which could be an issue for my media transfer.

What's the best filesystem to share between OS X and Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As seen in the comparison table here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Supporting_operating_systems

The only sure thing you have is FAT16 and FAT32. This is because HFS was left for HFS+ in Mac but HFS+ is not very "compatible" in linux just yet.

Anyway if you want to have support fot higher file sizes you could try NTFS but here is the catch (Which is not that difficult anyway) you need NTFS-3G in both ubuntu and mac.

Ubuntu already comes with NTFS-3G which gives complete Read/Write access to a NTFS filesystem. Mac does only READ unless you have NTFS-3G installed.

For what i know you can find the NTFS-3G for mac here: http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/

But there might be other places.